# Is the following active or passive?

Tags: active-vs-passive

Is the following sentence active or passive? Or can we say it is active and it is also passive?

> They were absolutely fascinated by the game.

Answer (score 1):

If the game is the subject,

> The game absolutely fascinated them.

Is active voice, while

> They were absolutely fascinated by the game

Is passive voice.